# The Possibility of a "True" Quiz Generator

Tags: parsing, artificial-intelligence, automated-tests

I've been given an assignment to create a program that might involve a quiz generator. I decided to come to you guys since you seem to be the most helpful.

Is an automatic quiz generator possible?

Is it that automatic, or do you have to enter your own questions and correct answers?

Can it work for other things rather than boolean answers (true and false)?

Can it observe text syntax so that it can create questions based on a paragraph of information?

can it observe text syntax so that it can accept answers that are close to the right answer, but is off by a few words?

This would be very helpful if you could help me, as this question has me stumped right now.
You guys always come through though, so I await your answer :D!

P.S. - I've seen other questions like this, but it covered only stuff like randomization. I believe that would be possible, but I'm wondering if **"true"**  generators are possible.

Comment: why is android / blackberry on this?  or java or c++?  This should be tagged artificial-intelligence, nlp, nlg, for starters.  And be on a different forum.

Comment: @Atrey: Yeah, I wonder if there should be a http://pleasedomyhomeworkforme.stackexchange.com for these questions.

Comment: @martin or a domydissertation one.

Comment: @Khalspi - I think you are asking the wrong question.  You should be asking is this **feasible** as an XXX week programming assignment.

Comment: I'm sorry you guys are angry, but I didn't mean assignment as homework. I wasn't even asking you guys for code snippets. I was just wondering if it was possible to do text quiz generators or if I was wasting my time...

Comment: @Atreys: I put those because I was unsure of what other tags to enter, also, the application I'm planning to make will be made with c++ or java and it will be for android/blackberry platforms.

Comment: @Khalspi If you're unsure about which tags to apply, and apply such a wide range of tags, then the question does not belong on SO because it cannot be answered. Your question is tantamount to asking "Should I buy a car or should I go eat dinner? Or perhaps browse the web? What's the right thing to do?" In this specific case there's too many questions in your one post, so it is hard to answer specifically.

Comment: @Lasse: I think I understand what you're saying, but what i really wanted was a...an outline if you will. I was planning on creating an application that could read - for example- a student's school notes, and convert it into a quiz to help the student for an exam!
I want to know if its possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598713/computer-ai-algorithm-to-write-sentences 

This is just like my question, but I want questions not sentences!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is an automatic quiz generator possible?

It depends on what you call automatic, and what you consider a successful level of functionality.  *Something* is definitely possible.

> Is it that automatic, or do you have to enter your own questions and correct answers?  Can it observe text syntax so that it can create questions based on a paragraph of information?

Yes, that's possible, but again there's a spectrum from only working for the simplest text and being easily confused (which is relatively easy to program - even a regular expression parser could do that), through to handling arbitrary real-world textual sources and getting say 80%+ of the facts out of the text and posing sensible questions for which it correctly identified the answer (which might take a team of 100 language and programming experts decades).  Language analysis is difficult.  If you want proof - try converting a paragraph of English text to another language using Babelfish or similar online translator, then convert it back... :-).

> Can it work for other things rather than boolean answers (true and false)?

Of course, but again the more complex you make it, the less likely you'll get anything that works...

> can it observe text syntax so that it can accept answers that are close to the right answer, but is off by a few words?

It could, but the range of ways someone might phrase an answer is so varied that having to follow a simple template with a few words' tolerance wouldn't work well in general use.

**General thoughts**

Why don't you search for existing educational quiz programs to get an idea of what other people have achieved...?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll browse around, but I just thought the idea was too good to be true. I had high hopes for it though!

Comment: Khalspi: Yes - would be wonderful if this kind of analysis could be done more successfully... people really have been working on it for decades, so it's a tough nut.  I think you would be interested in something like Eliza (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELIZA) - it could be a fun way to start understanding the problem domain, and you could download the source code and start making enhancements.

Comment: I've just read about something called a Markov string (correct?) which creates text from a sample. That is close to my idea, but I'm not sure if that Markov parody or whatever is accurate enough.

Comment: I'll check out ELiza! Thanks for your input!!

Comment: @Khalspi: Markov string substitutions sounds like they might be useful in inserting particular words into question templates.  That's the easy bit though - working out which words to insert is massively harder :-/.  Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

I would make an automatic math quiz generator, as a simple example.

Questions could be generated easily, just come up with 2 random numbers that fit certain characteristics, and randomly add/subtract/multiply them. Then mathematically add them together.

But, for non-math subjects, a quiz generator would be more difficult, it would need some kind of a database to draw from of sample questions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I meant, if it was possible for a generator to draw textual clues from say, a paragraph and just formulate quiz questions.

Comment: @Khalspi: Anything is possible, if you try hard enough. The thing you desire seems to be quite complex. You'd have to figure out how to divide sentences into parts, and ask questions. In order for it to be any good, you'd have to have a pretty extensive complex database. Good luck!

Comment: I hope I can do it! I'm glad at least you and a few others understand what I'm saying...man I got seriously dissed...

Answer (score 2):

> Is an automatic quiz generator possible?

Yes, an automatic quiz general is possible.

> Is it that automatic, or do you have to enter your own questions and correct answers?

You *could* make it automated, but that would require access to a large database and very complex data mining algorithms. If it's an assignment, you would probably be better off having it take in questions and their corresponding answers. A mathematics quiz generator would be much easier to implement, as it would only require random operators and operands placed in the correct sequence.

> Can it work for other things rather than boolean answers (true and false)?

This depends entirely on your implementation, but theoretically yes.

> Can it observe text syntax so that it can create questions based on a paragraph of information?

If you have an awesome data mining script and resources to form grammatically-correct sentences with raw information, then yes.

> can it observe text syntax so that it can accept answers that are close to the right answer, but is off by a few words?

Producing an algorithm to reliably evaluate different sentences with the same meanings as the same would be *very* difficult. You would need to account for spelling and grammatical errors as well as synonyms and many other factors. Furthermore, it would be very language (not programming language) dependent.

I hope this answered some of your questions.

Comment: Thanks, lovely answer. I didn't expect that people would flare up at me like this though, I was asking if it was feasible. However you've given me some good thoughts. More than likely though, a beginner like me can't do that. If you guys do it though I'd like to be a part of that project!